# Can't Open My App in Production | DeepLink React Native | React Navigation v5/v6

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

hope you guys have a great day!
I'm in the middle of learning deeplink in react native, currently I've managed to open my app via cmd using `npx uri-scheme open myapp://inv/12321312 --android`, and the page I'm going to is also already open along with the `:id` I included in the link

now i have released my app (not yet uploaded in playstore - but just run `npx react-native run-android --variant=release`), then why when i access `myapp://inv/12321312` link in my browser, my app doesn't open?

i'm using `Google Chrome` in my **`android device`**

please help:(

Answer (score 0):

in app.json add intentFilters for android 
if you are using expo

```
{
  "expo": {
    "scheme": "myapp",
     .....
    "android": {
     ...
      "intentFilters": [
        {
          "action": "VIEW",
          "autoVerify": true,
          "data": [
            {
              "scheme": "https",
              "host": "myapp.com",
              "pathPrefix": "/"
            },
            {
              "scheme": "myapp",
              "host": "*",
              "pathPrefix": "/"
            }
          ],
          "category": [
            "BROWSABLE",
            "DEFAULT"
          ]
        }
      ]
       ...
    },
  }
}
```

or if you are using react native CLI

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking#adding-filters

after that generate APK for Android

and send https://myapp.com/ in message whatsapp 
click this link from chat 
it's work ^^

update : (test)
ios => after build ipa for test ios run this link in your browser phone when app installed : myapp://

android => after build apk for test android send in this link in message (email , whatsapp, ...) and click link for test (after installed app)

Comment: I tried this way but not working

Comment: @fatmamahmoud Please share your code, so I can help you solve a problem

Comment: I saw your question like this and I have sent an answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/73406398/14724559