# deep-linking not working after the app on production

Tags: react-native, expo, deep-linking

I created my app with react-native expo and added deep-linking and I tested the deep-linking on develop and on simulator and it is working fine "npx uri-scheme open myapp://orders --android"
but when try to open this "https://myschema.com/orders" on my android device through chrome not open the app
the app.json is

```
{
   "expo":{
      "scheme": "myapp",
      "android": {
          //........
          "intentFilters": [
             {
               "action": "VIEW",
               "autoVerify": true,
               "data": [
                  {
                    "scheme": "https",
                    "host": "myapp.com",
                    "pathPrefix": "/"
                  }
                ],
              "category": [
                 "BROWSABLE",
                 "DEFAULT"
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this for test ios

```
{
   "scheme": "myapp",
   "host": "*",
   "pathPrefix": "/"
 }
```

Your new code will be like:

```
{
   "expo":{
      "scheme": "myapp",
      "android": {
          //........
          "intentFilters": [
             {
               "action": "VIEW",
               "autoVerify": true,
               "data": [
                  {
                    "scheme": "https",
                    "host": "myapp.com",
                    "pathPrefix": "/"
                  },
                  {
                    "scheme": "myapp",
                    "host": "*",
                    "pathPrefix": "/"
                  }
                ],
              "category": [
                 "BROWSABLE",
                 "DEFAULT"
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
    }
}
```

**ios =>** after build `ipa` for test ios run this link in your browser phone when app installed : myapp://

**android =>**  after build `apk` for test android send in this link in message (email , whatsapp, ...) and click link for test **(after installed app)**